# How to retrieve data in view of Laravel 5 framework

Tags: php, laravel-5

There are two options to retrieve data in views in Laravel 5.

1. Transfer from the controller to views
2. Use `@inject()` command in views

I need to transfer data from table to combobox, which one might be better?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can query the data from DB in controller and pass it to view:

```
    $users = Users::all();
    return view('index')->with(compact('users'));
```

OR

```
    return view('index')->with('users', $users);
```

Here is how you can access in  view(blade.php)

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    {!! $user->first_name !!}
@endforeach
```

Comment: i now that, but i have a partial and it need the same data!